# Can I (how do I) use Jade shorthand when passing parameters into a Jade file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm playing around with Nodejs, and am wondering if I can use jade style shorthand (ie

```
a(href='/page?name=contact')
```

as part of an argument passed into a jade file.

---

Say, for example, that I want to write something along the lines of (from the Ninja Store example):

```
 var name = req.query.name;
    var contents = {
        about: 'a(href="/page?name=about") Ninja Store \n sells the coolest ninja stuff in the world. Anyone shopping here is cool.',
        contact: 'You can contact us at <address><strong>Ninja Store</strong>,<br>1, World Ninja Headquarters,<br>Ninja Avenue,<br>NIN80B7-JP,<br>Nihongo.</address>'
    };
res.render('page', { title: 'Ninja Store - ' + name, username: req.session.username, content:contents[name] });
```

Is there a mechanism I can use to write this style of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to [compile the string](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a5):

```
var jade = require('jade');

// ...

var contents = {
    about: jade.compile('a(href="/page?name=about") ...')(),
    contact: 'You can contact us at ...'
};
```

However, you could just switch between views rather than storing them in `contents`:

```
res.render(name, {
    title: 'Ninja Store - ' + name,
    username: req.session.username
});
```

Aand, you can still have them contained in `page.jade` with [template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11).

page.jade:

```
#container
    block contents
```

about.jade:

```
inherits page

block contents
    a(href="/page?name=about") Ninja Store
    span sells the coolest ninja stuff in the world. Anyone shopping here is cool.
```

Comment: Thanks! Compiling the string solves it. I'm generating the string dynamically, and haven't figured out a way to do that work in the jade file.